# Find a T such that T maps the real axis onto itself and the imaginary axis onto the circle $|w-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a linear fractional transformation T such that T maps the real axis onto itself and the imaginary axis onto the circle $|w-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$

I have no idea how to do this kind of problem, anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: The real and the imaginary axis intersect in $0$ and in $\infty$. Your desired circles intersect in $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is common knowledge that Möbius transformations (or fractional transformation) are completely determined if we fix three points.

As Daniel Fisher points out, to specify the transformation you want, consider $T$ such that $T(0) = 0$, $T(\infty) = 1$ (or if it makes you feel more comfortable, $T^{-1}(1)=\infty$). With this information, $T$ must be of the form:
$$
T(z) = \frac{z}{z+d},
$$
You've already guaranteed that the imaginary line maps to a circle that passes through $0$ and $1$. Now you just need fix the third point to know which circle. To do this observe that $d$ must be real.

**Note:** The inverse of $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is $T^{-1}(z) = \frac{-dz+b}{cz-a}$